# Clarification about @Spy and @InjectMocks inside a @Service Spring Boot

Tags: java, mockito

Well, i am very confused about @Spy and @Mock. In my understand @Spy will call real methods and @Mock/@InjectMocks don't, because it just a mock, then i need a stub (when.thenReturn) if i would like to change the behavior of a mock.

In my test class i have this code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CaixaServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CaixaService caixaService;

    @Mock
    private CaixaRepository caixaRepository;
```

So, CaixaRepository is a JpaRepository interface from Spring Data and CaixaService just have a very simple method:

```
public void calcular(){
        int a = (int) Math.pow(1,3);
        log.info(a);
    }
```

If i call `caixaRepository.findOne(id)` null should be returned because findOne is never called really, because it just a mock. This case works very well.

But when i call `caixaService.calcular()` the method body is executed (shouldn't because it is a mock), so `log.info(a)` is logged on my file.

I can't understand this behavior, because as i said in my understand @InjectMocks or @Mock shouldn't execute anything if stub not exists, this a @Spy task.

Comment: The service is not a mock. It's a real object, where the mocks are injected by Mockito. If everything was mocked, you would test any single line of your code.

Comment: The service isn't a mock, it's properly instantiated, but its members filled with mocks

Comment: So InjectMocks works like Spy ?

Comment: No. InjectMocks simply creates a real instance of the object, and injects the mocks and spies, which are found thanks the the Mock and Spy annotations. Why don't you read the javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is right but your understanding of `@InjectMocks`.
Indeed annotating a field with it will not create a mock object as you think.
Instead of, it will try to inject the mock dependencies to the object referenced by the field where the annotation is.
Note that this way of injecting the dependencies is not explicit and so doesn't document the dependencies to mock in your test.
Besides if the dependencies injection fails, Mockito will not report any failure.

Comment: What do you suggest as a best practice to injecting my mock dependencies ?

Comment: Inject it with `@Mock`, no problem for that. But I would set them in the object under test in a `@Before/@BeforeEach` (JUnit 4 / 5) method from the constructor call such as `foo = new Foo(barMock, otherBarMock);`

Comment: It's true, in this way i follow the best practices in OO. Thanks @davidxxx

Comment: so i should remove the InjectMocks and create "new CaixaService(mock1,mock2..)" right ?